# 'handleListKeyDown', which lacks return-type annotation

Tags: typescript

```
function handleListKeyDown = useCallback((event: React.KeyboardEvent) {
  if (event.key === 'Tab') {
    event.preventDefault();
    setOpen(false);
  }
}, [open]);
```

I got error:

> 'handleListKeyDown', which lacks return-type annotation, implicitly
>   has an 'any' return type.

Which type should I return in order to fulfill TypeScript expectations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might be focusing on the first error in the compiler output and not getting the bigger picture:

```
function handleListKeyDown =
//       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ~
// return annotation ---^  ^--- '(' expected
```

There's a `'(' expected.(1005)` error because `function foo =` is not valid syntax in either JavaScript or TypeScript.  Either you need to make `handleListKeyDown` a valid function statement `function handleListKeyDown(...) {...}` or make `handleListKeyDown` a variable/constant like `const handleListKeyDown = ...`.  I don't know what you're doing (I don't have `useCallback()` etc definitions) so I can't advise further.  Hopefully you'll be able to proceed once you fix the initial syntax problem.